# Understanding member access with inheritance / friend class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend-class

from C++ primer 5th edition:
have a look at these classes:

```
class Base {
    friend class Pal;
public:
    void pub_mem();
protected:
    int prot_mem;
private:
    int priv_mem;
};

class Sneaky : public Base {
private:
    int j;
};

class Pal {
public:
    int f1(Base b){
        return b.prot_mem;  //OK, Pal is friend class
    }

    int f2(Sneaky s){
        return s.j;  //error: Pal not friend, j is private
    }

    int f3(Sneaky s){
        return s.prot_mem; //ok Pal is friend
    }
}
```

Here Pal is a friend class of Base, while Sneaky inherits from Base and is used in Pal.
Now the very last line where `s.prot_mem` is invoked, author gives the reason it works because Pal is a friend class of Base. But what i read so far, my understanding tells me that it should work anywawy, because s derives from Base and prot_mem is protected member of Base Class, which should have already access to Sneaky, can you explain why i am wrong or some more elaboration please?

Comment: If your question is about whether the code should compile _anyway_ without friendship, you could have posted it *without* friendship in the first place. It would have been much clearer. Also, the tag friend-class does not help in any way to classify this question, because you're actually asking about the behaviour _without_ friendship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my understanding tells me that it should work anyway, because s
>   derives from Base and prot_mem is protected member of Base Class,
>   which should have already access to Sneaky

No, protected variable `prot_mem` can only be accessed by derived class member, but not by third party class member, like `class Pal`, if `Pal` is not a friend of `Base`.

Comment: oh oh now i understand, when we use an Object in another class, then anything doing s.member or s->member (if pointer) can only fetch "public" members, right??

Answer (score 1):

Without friendship, `Pal` only sees Sneaky or Base's public members. The fact that one member of `Base` is protected does not benefit `Pal` in any way - it only benefits `Sneaky`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that while `Sneaky` can access `prot_mem`, the code you're showing is not in `Sneaky`, it's in `Pal`. If `Pal` was an unrelated class, it couldn't access `prot_mem`, which is also protected in `Sneaky`. However, `Pal` is a friend of `Base`, which gives it the access necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks but isn't when we pass Sneaky object as argument and call s.prot_mem; the access is invoked by Sneaky and not by Pal???

Comment: @Jason Access protection checks whether the *code* performing the access has the correct rights. Where does the code which performs the read of `s.prot_mem` live? It's in class `Pal`, so it has `Pal`'s access rights. IOW, the access is invoked **by** `Pal` **on** `Sneaky`.